# jQuery colorbox: how do I prevent the loading indicator small box from appearing before the main colorbox content does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm using jQuery colorbox to load a login form (via ajax). However, this little small box shows up for a few seconds, then it fades into the actual content that I want to load. So after observing several [colorbox examples](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/) on the website, I'm somewhat sure that the little box is supposed to be a pre-loading box. Is there any way I could disable this box from appearing entirely?

I've tried silly things like tweaking the CSS and setting `display: none` to all loading items, but it doesn't work.

[image]

**I want to avoid any CSS hacks and solve this problem by modifying the javascript.**  Ideally, some way for the loading box to never show up, as I won't be using colorbox for anything that takes a long time to load.

Recreated the problem on jsfiddle using my modified colorbox javascript and CSS. The ajax content won't load there, but the little box that I want to get rid of still shows up: http://jsfiddle.net/hPEXf/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would hide the color box with display:none !important and then see if there is an event for when the ajax load is complete and then set the color box to display:block

Comment: @PedroEstrada that sounds like a quick hack for something that should be appropriately fixed with javascript though. :/ I'm not keep on using `display: none` as it slows down page load

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @op1ekun said `ColorBox` has two events that are useful in your situation.

> `onOpen` -> Callback that fires right before ColorBox begins to open.
>
> `onComplete` -> Callback that fires right after loaded content is displayed.

It seems simply just hiding lightbox using either `display:none` or `$("#colorbox").hide()` don't work. so I used `opacity` to hide the lightbox while content gets loaded. I've set up a jsfiddle by forking yours http://jsfiddle.net/fDd6v/2/ that demonstrate this in action. Here is the code that has been used:

```
$(function(){
    $("#awesome-link").colorbox({
        onOpen: function(){
            $("#colorbox").css("opacity", 0);
        },
        onComplete: function(){
            $("#colorbox").css("opacity", 1);
        }
    });
});
```

- Refrence: [ColorBox - a jQuery lightbox Events/Callbacks docs](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox#setting-onopen)

Comment: display: none worked better for me, using opacity: 0 made it skip the transitioning effect in all calls except the first load.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the following in the CSS -

```
#colorbox{border: 1px solid #ebebeb;}    
#cboxContent{background:#fff; overflow:hidden;padding: 20px;}
```

to this -

```
#colorbox{border: 0px solid #ebebeb;}
#cboxContent{background:#fff; overflow:hidden;padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
```

And the box is hidden until it expands to show the content. I'm not sure if that will be detrimental to your overall style though. You should be able to manipulate the margin of the form so that you get white space around it.

http://jsfiddle.net/hPEXf/1/

Comment: Hmm.. Unfortunately the actual content that loads will have no padding as well. I was hoping to somehow eliminate the need for the little box (loading box?) to show up entirely through javascript so that the CSS doesn't need so much tweaking. Thank you though :)

Comment: The loading box is expanded to show the content so you need to start it out with the changes that I have made. I made a change to the actual content container, in this case #cboxError, to give it some padding using margin. I think you just have to add margins to  #cboxLoadedContent

Comment: @Michelle - You and Jay are both correct. The "loading box" is the actual container of the content that is displayed. The plugin author cleverly uses it to show an in-progress-activity indicator during the loading process, which using Ajax, can be slow enough to warrant posting an indicator. I'm not aware of any simple way to change that behavior short of forking the plugin and revising it.

Comment: IMHO using the built-in events is much better than a css hack or forking the library and changing the library js code.

Answer (score 2):

I was working with ColorBox few days ago so I believe I'm quite fresh on the topic. Did You consider using built-in callbacks?

Specifically `onOpen` and `onComplete`?

If we go with the padding solution mentioned by Jay you can set padding to `0` in the `onOpen` and set it back to desired value in the `onComplete`.

It seems to be a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with

```
$(function(){
    $("#awesome-link").colorbox({
        onOpen: function(){
            $("#colorbox").css("opacity", 0);
        },
        onComplete: function(){
            $("#colorbox").css("opacity", 1);
        }
    });
});
```

But it turns to black fade then open `color-box` when i'm working with `transition:"fade"` properties of colorbox.

Now i change my code in `jquery.colorbox.js`

comment or remove the below code in `colorbox js` file

```
                /*var initialWidth = setSize(settings.get('initialWidth'), 'x');
                var initialHeight = setSize(settings.get('initialHeight'), 'y');
                var maxWidth = settings.get('maxWidth');
                var maxHeight = settings.get('maxHeight');

                settings.w = (maxWidth !== false ? Math.min(initialWidth, setSize(maxWidth, 'x')) : initialWidth) - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth;
                settings.h = (maxHeight !== false ? Math.min(initialHeight, setSize(maxHeight, 'y')) : initialHeight) - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight;

                $loaded.css({width:'', height:settings.h});
                */


                /*$loadingOverlay = $([$tag(div, "LoadingOverlay")[0],$tag(div,"LoadingGraphic")[0]]);  */                                                                

                 $slideshow = $tag('button', "Slideshow")/*,
                 $loadingOverlay*/

                 /*  clearTimeout(loadingTimer);
                 $loadingOverlay.hide();*/

                 /* loadingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                 $loadingOverlay.show();
                  }, 100);*/
```

And change the below code

```
             overlay.css({
                    opacity: opacity === opacity ? opacity : '',
                    cursor: settings.get('overlayClose') ? 'pointer' : '',
                    visibility: 'visible'
              }).show(500);
```

To,

```
             setTimeout(function(){     
                 $overlay.css({
                       opacity: opacity === opacity ? opacity : '',
                       cursor: settings.get('overlayClose') ? 'pointer' : '',
                       visibility: 'visible'
                  }).fadeIn(500);
      }, 600);
```

and now it's working smoothly.